# Encryption Exception in production environment

Tags: java, tomcat, encryption

I am having a problem on our production environment with encryption.

The below code is the source of the issue:

```
public static void standardExceptionHandling(Exception exc, Logger alog) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
    exc.printStackTrace(pw);
    alog.info(sw.toString()); /* Line 292 */
}

/**
 * Method that takes a key/value set, converts it into a standard web parameter string
 * and then encrypts the string.
 *
 * @param values the key value set
 * @return the encrypted string
 *
 */
public static String encrypt(Map<String, String> values) {
    StringBuilder unencrypted = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> value : values.entrySet()) {
        if (first) {
            first = false;
        } else {
            unencrypted.append("&");
        }
        unencrypted.append(value.getKey())
                .append("=")
                .append(value.getValue());
    }

    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(AES_KEY.getBytes(), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(unencrypted.toString().getBytes("UTF8"));

        String enc = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(encrypted);
        return enc;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        standardExceptionHandling(e, log);
        return "";
    }
}

/**
 * Method that takes an encrypted string containing a standard web parameter string
 * and converts it to a key/value set
 *
 * @param encrypted the encrypted string
 * @return the key value set
 */
public static Map<String, String> decrypt(String encrypted) {
    String decrypted = "";
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(AES_KEY.getBytes(), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
        byte[] dec = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encrypted);
        decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(dec), "UTF8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        standardExceptionHandling(e, log);
    }

    Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (String pair : decrypted.split("&")) {
        String[] split_pair = pair.split("=");
        String key, value;
        if (split_pair.length == 1) {
            key = split_pair[0];
            value = "";
        } else if (split_pair.length == 2) {
            key = split_pair[0];
            value = split_pair[1];
        } else if (split_pair.length > 2) {
            log.debug("Error when decrypting string, parameter found with more than 2 parts (" + pair + ")");
            continue;
        } else {
            // We should never reach this, as it is impossible to split a string into a 0 length array.
            log.debug("The impossible happened, we split a String into a 0 length array (" + pair + ")");
            continue;
        }
        // This is only reach when key and value have been initialised thank to the continue statements when we hit
        // an error state.
        values.put(key, value);
    }
    return values;
}
```

There is no exception thrown when encrypting the text.
After encryption, it is pass back via a URL through a servlet

i.e http://URL/servlet?hash=TVgYDScPqQ3eaJfEBmwuSCZUN0GCEshOBZ9H0YKH%2BS2b96BYdLRPBa6Dl8Z0mMmpPM1r2uxdv0sq%0A5BNbWTMcww%3D%3D

On our production server we get the following exception:

```
INFO 10/mar/2017 06:02:37 [http-nio-80-exec-104] (HelperMethods.java:292) - javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:913)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:824)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:436)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
at com.gg.gomoenterprise.utils.HelperMethods.decrypt(HelperMethods.java:349)
at com.gg.gomomessenger.servlets.EmailServlet.doPost(EmailServlet.java:60)
at com.gg.gomomessenger.servlets.EmailServlet.doGet(EmailServlet.java:46)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
DEBUG 10/mar/2017 06:02:37 [http-nio-80-exec-104] (EmailServlet.java:88) - com.gg.gomomessenger.commons.exceptions.EmailSeverletException: <h1>We do not see your email address in this program. You may have already unsubscribed or be subscribed with a different email address. If you need assistance, email support@mymobilemsg.com.</h1>
at com.gg.gomomessenger.commons.exceptions.EmailSeverletException.dataMisingException(EmailSeverletException.java:39)
at com.gg.gomomessenger.servlets.EmailOptInServlet.handleOpt(EmailOptInServlet.java:91)
at com.gg.gomomessenger.servlets.EmailServlet.doPost(EmailServlet.java:82)
at com.gg.gomomessenger.servlets.EmailServlet.doGet(EmailServlet.java:46)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is only happening on production, not local, dev or staging.
All servers run Tomcat 8.0.26

**Local JRE**
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

**Staging  JRE**
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)

**Stagin JRE**
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)

**Production JRE**
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)

Could this be a code issue?

Comment: On debugging what is the data length (length of `dec`), it must be a multiple of the block size, 16-bytes for AES? Error message: "Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher" says it all.

Comment: You use that code in a production environment?  It uses ECB mode... you should probably fix that.

Comment: @LukePark, not very helpful.... could you tell me what do use. Rather than just say "fix it"

Also, this is not meant to be a major encryption algorithm, it is simply to obscure 4 parameters from the user.

If we didn't encrypt, we would be passing 4 params and they all need to match one another (all different but linked). If they dont link correctly, page wont load!

Comment: I kind of expected you were capable of doing your own research as to why ECB is bad.  Use GCM instead if you can.

Comment: Do not use ECB mode, it is insecure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to be secret.

Answer (score 2):

I notice that the example:

`TVgYDScPqQ3eaJfEBmwuSCZUN0GCEshOBZ9H0YKH%2BS2b96BYdLRPBa6Dl8Z0mMmpPM1r2uxdv0sq%0A5BNbWTMcww%3D%3D`

is URL encoded and contains a linefeed character (%0A). The Base64 needs to be have the URL encoding removed.

Also the Base64 encoding should not add linefeed characters, there should be an option for that. In any event they need to  be stripped on Base64 decoding.

Correctly decoded it is in hex:

`4D58180D270FA90DDE6897C4066C2E48265437418212C84E059F47D18287F92D9BF7A05874B44F05AE8397C67498C9A93CCD6BDAEC5DBF4B2AE4135B59331CC3`

Comment: Point taken... I had missed that the URLDecode even though the encrypt does URLEncode, thanks!

However, do you have any explanation as to why it was working with the exact same setup in other environments.

Comment: Luck. Depending on the encrypted data there may not be "+" and "/" in the Base64 encoding and depending on the length no trailing "=" characters to UIRL encode. the line feed 0x0A is generally removed by the Base64 decode function.

Comment: Although, I really like your answer and definitely see that as a problem.... I really am surprised it was just luck that it only happened in PROD.

However, on the flip side, we didn't test much,.... we did an emergency fix to go back to remove the encryption. Maybe some hashes wouyd have worked in production.

Comment: Hashes wouldn't have worked either, it's the base64 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

As @zaph pointed out, there is likely a problem parsing the cipher text, which leads to a cipher text of a length different from a multiple of the block size (`16 bytes`). After correctly encoding and decoding the cipher text, you should be able to verify that the cipher text length is *n * 16* bytes.

In addition, the line where you get an instance of the `Cipher` class, `Cipher.getInstance("AES");` is not ideal. `AES` by default in Java is `AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding` (but this can also differ by provider). `ECB` is a non-recommended/deprecated/broken [block cipher mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation). Aside from unknowingly selecting a poor mode of operation, the ambiguity here is unnecessary. Evaluate the available modes and explicitly select the proper one (likely `GCM`, or possibly `CBC` or `CTR` in conjunction with a strong HMAC function).

You should also be using a unique and non-predictable initialization vector (IV) for each message encryption.

Comment: Please show where ECB mode is a deprecated/broken block cipher mode.

Comment: @zaph: That ECB is insecure is common knowledge: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20941/why-shouldnt-i-use-ecb-encryption

Comment: Perhaps those terms are strong, but depending on your threat model, I stand by them. The obvious example is the ["penguin image"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), but there are [many](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/20946/12569) [other](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/968/12569) [examples](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/62084/16485) of `ECB` mode being insecure against modern cryptanalysis.

Comment: That ECB is insecure does not mean it is deprecated/broken. Deprecated is is a formal statement, broken implies there was a time when it was not broken. There are use cases where ECB mode can be used. If you look at my commenting you will see where I often rail against ECB mode and it seems to be generally used by those who do not know better and cases where it is inappropriate.

Comment: I don't want to get pedantic with this discussion. Yes, there are corner cases where ECB can be used. For a mobile messaging system available to the public (as is the case in the poster's question), there is no legitimate reason to use ECB and it is a disservice to their users. I think most non-cryptographers would accept that if a cipher is *insecure*, for their intents and purposes, it is *broken*.

Comment: I think most non-cryptographers would accept that if a cipher is insecure, for their intents and purposes, it is bad design. Even MD5 has uses where it is not "broken".

Comment: Just talked to my crypto [SME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject-matter_expert) and was told that ECB is not deprecated and that it is currently still being used in critical applications. My point is to be careful with wording WRT crypto. Examples of deprecation are NIST officially deprecating DES and 3DES with double-length keys.

Comment: I agree terms matter. It also matters that cryptography has a different glossary and interpretations of things than other developers are familiar with. The [colloquial (SW) definition of "deprecated"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation#Software_deprecation) accurately expresses the meaning I was trying to convey to a larger audience. If I were discussing this with NIST engineers, I would have used a different term. Something can be correct and yet not as useful as possible, and that puts an unnecessary, and sometimes unseen, burden on the audience.

Comment: The solution here is simple, the answer could be updated. The other thing about crypto is many things are not just personal preference like indentation, it is more engineering that the usual free-for-all coding.

Comment: Guys,  I have given you my code. Encryption is not my forte, which algorithm should I be using? Please remember that this is not a HUGE highly secure algorithm. It is simply to obscure 4 parameters from a user. If we didn't encrypt, we would be passing 4 parameters and they all need to match one another (all different but linked). If they dont link correctly, page wont load! List to choose from is: AES (**NOI!!!!!**), AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding (**?**), ECB(**NO, Weak**),GCM (**?**),CBC or CTR(**?**)

Comment: Use `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` with an `Hmac/Sha-256` authentication tag over the cipher text or `AES/GCM/NoPadding`. Both are readily available in Java. You should read the Wikipedia article I linked in my answer to at least understand their attributes and why you are using them.